# Using TortoiseGit to clone from SVN repo ssh

Tags: git, svn, ssh, tortoisegit

I am trying to clone from a SVN repo using TortoiseSVN and SSH.  My URL is correct and I can use TortoiseGit to browse to my repo, however when it tries to clone it I get the following output:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/path/of/project/.git/
Can't create session: Unable to connect to a repository at URL
'svn+ssh://path/to/repo': Error in child process: exec of 
'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe' failed: 
No such file or directory at /mingw64/share/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 148.
```

I have tried with and without loading my putty key, however the output is the same either way.  Anyone know why it isn't able to connect?

Comment: Which version of Git for Windows are you using? Looks like an old version and thus, the space in the SVN_SSH environemnt variable breaks Git SVN.

Comment: @MrTux I am using git version 2.10.1.windows.1
I was able to get this working though.  I had to make sure that my SSH client path was correct and matched the same SSH client that TortoiseSVN was using

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my issue by going to settings -> network in TortoiseGit.  I switched my SSH client like so:

From:

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoisePlink.exe
```

To:

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe
```

This way TortoiseGit used the TortoisePlink.exe file that I knew was working for SVN.

Comment: The tortoiseplink binary of TortoiseGit and TortoiseSVN are equivalent... This can't be the reason. As you could see in the error message it was already using this tortoiseplink.exe. I suppose that your environment variable was borked and by setting it again yaou fixed it.